# Correct SQL-syntax of a table-alias?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Do these two SQL-statements mean the same?

```
Statement 1: SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1 WHERE 1  
Statement 2: SELECT * FROM table1 t1 WHERE 1
```

And is the second statement correct in MySQL/MariaDB and SQL-standard?

Comment: They both look correct to me

Comment: `as` is optional. Including it or not is a personal choice, subject to opinion. I always put it in, but that's just me.

Comment: Yes, they're identical.  `AS` is an optional keyword.

Comment: Does the documentation not cover this?

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the SQL-99 standard: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/select-statement/

*Correlation name* is the proper terminology for what people commonly call a "table alias."

```
<Table reference> ::=
[ ONLY ]{<Table name> | <query name>} [ [ AS ] <Correlation name> [ (<derived Column list>) ] ] |
<Table subquery> [ AS ] <Correlation name> [ (<derived Column list>) ] |
<joined Table> |
LATERAL (<query expression>) [ AS ] <Correlation name> [ (<derived Column list>) ]
```

Notice the keyword `AS` is within its own square brackets, indicating that it is optional, even when you declare a correlation name for the table or subquery.

This is found the MySQL manual for [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

> A table reference can be aliased using `tbl_name AS alias_name` or `tbl_name alias_name`...

Weird trivia: For some reason unknown to me Oracle does not allow the `AS` keyword for correlation names. Go figure.

---

This also applies to `AS` used for a column alias.

> You can use the optional AS name clause to specify a name for a Column expression; it will be used to identify that result for the entire SELECT statement. The required syntax for a select list is as follows.

Okay, that's not completely clear that the `AS` keyword is optional. But the syntax reference shows the following:

```
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ] Column list

Column list ::=
   expression [ [ AS ] <Column name> ] [ , ... ] |
   *
```

Again, in the MySQL manual for [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

> The `AS` keyword is optional when aliasing a `select_expr` with an identifier.

There are a few other cases where SQL keywords are optional. For example, `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are identical operations.

That's what you get with a language designed by committee.

Comment: The question was about table aliases (correlation names)

Comment: @wildplasser, thanks, I overlooked that. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, second statement is correct!
I've tested at my end. But, you should use the first statement!

Comment: Hahaha, just made me laugh that you tested the first one but insist on OP using the second one. They are identical statements. Funny!

Comment: Look at @BillKarwin answer. Thats an answer, this is a comment!

Comment: This type of  answer attracts downvotes
___I did not DV___ and if that happens you will loose rep points and take longer to get to 50 reps.
Until you have 50 reps stick to questions that are well asked and therefore easily answered without needing clarification

Answer (score -2):

Yes, they mean the same. Both are correct.

Comment: Look at @BillKarwin answer. Thats an answer, this is a comment!

Comment: This type of  answer attracts downvotes
___I did not DV___ and if that happens you will loose rep points and take longer to get to 50 reps.
Until you have 50 reps stick to questions that are well asked and therefore easily answered without needing clarification

Comment: @RiggsFolly : the billKarvin answer is actually wrong (or it is a correct answer to a different question ;-) . It is about column aliases, not table akiases (correlation names)

Comment: @wildplasser But you agree with the gist of my comment I hope